# Ignore Unavailable Slicer Items in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having trouble creating a code to select slicer items on my excel table. There is a connection/query with the table and the data is updated every hour (some of the options/rows may disappear).

For example:

Now the slicer item "10" is available and the code runs with no problems, but this row may go away when I update the data from the server and the macro gives me the error "

```
run-time error 5 

invalid procedure call or argument
```

This is the code I'm using:

```
Sub TechData()
'
' TechData Macro
'

'
    With ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Status2")
        .SlicerItems("10").Selected = True
        .SlicerItems("20").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("30").Selected = True
        .SlicerItems("40").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("50").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("90").Selected = False
    End With
End Sub
```

My intention is to create a code that ignores when an option is not available and change just those ones that are available.

I'm starting to learn vba and now it's a bit complicated for me.

Comment: How do you determine which ones are selected=true or false?

Comment: Have `On Error Resume Next` after the `With...` line, and `On Error GoTo 0` before the `End With` line; that will swallow all run-time errors. But really, you shouldn't be hard-coding any of this. Error 5 strikes me as weird though, I'd expect error 9 if e.g. `"20"` wasn't an item in the `SlicerItems` collection.

Comment: Also are you sure you want this to work of *whatever the active workbook is* and not one very specific workbook. Is the pivot table / slicer cache in the same workbook that's hosting your VBA code? If so then it's `ThisWorkbook` you want.

Comment: @RicardoDiaz There are two groups, A and B, for A we select 10 to 30 and 40 to 90.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Worked just fine! Thanks a lot! :D

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I have changed to ThisWorkbook, this is what I really wanted. Thank you!!!!!